# How to manipulate DataSet

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i have problem in manipulating DataSet, how can i filter rows without getting the whole records in tables.

here is my codes:

```
    For j As Integer = 0 To sDataSet.Tables(tran_ar_so_t.Name).Rows.Count - 1
        Dim nQty, nPrice, nAmount As Double
        With sDataSet.Tables(tran_ar_so_t.Name)
            nQty = IIf(.Rows(j).Item("nQty") Is DBNull.Value, 0, .Rows(j).Item("nQty")) : nPrice = IIf(.Rows(j).Item("nPrice") Is DBNull.Value, 0, .Rows(j).Item("nPrice"))
            ComputeNet(j)
            nAmount = net * nQty
            .Rows(j).Item("nAmountDue") = nAmount
        End With
    Next
```

Comment: I do not understand the question and do not understand how the code is related to the question. Could you give an example of what is happening and of what you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe DataTable.Select() method can resolve your problem; check this example:

```
    Dim filterCondition As String = "nQty > 10" 'A where statement you need
    Dim filteredRows As DataRow() = sDataSet.Tables(tran_ar_so_t.Name).Select(filterCondition)
```

Replace "nQty > 0" with your filtered condition, then in filteredRows you'll find only the DataRow that match with given condition.